# Chatwoot - Email Channel

Tags: gmail, gmail-imap, email-forwarding, gmail-pop, chatwoot

I have cloned the Chatwoot application code from Github and ran it in my local system. (https://github.com/chatwoot/chatwoot). Also, I have hosted the port:3000 using ngrok which was mentioned in their document. I am trying to create a channel for Email. When I enter my Email address, a forwarding address should be generated and we need to add this address as the forwarding address in our gmail settings.
But the domain name is missing in the forwarding address generated by the application.
The forwarding address looks like 'afc7cc27f45a9d40b0e8f851704be4e6@'
Do I need to configure something in the code? If yes, where should I configure it ?
Someone please help me find out a solution for this.

[image: Chatwoot app running in local]

Comment: Have you checked the env file? there is `MAILER_SENDER_EMAIL` field which can be modified. you can check a full sample from here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chatwoot/chatwoot/develop/.env.example